# Difference between google_project_iam_binding and google_project_iam_member

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

Hi terraform mates out there

I want to automate the role assignments process for service accounts and users on the Google Cloud Platform. I am actually thinking of [creating IAM custom roles](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam_custom_role) to get fine-grained roles terraform resources for different services, and assign that role to the users or service account I want to.

Checking the way to associate which members will get what roles, I am actually wondering what is the difference between use  [google_project_iam_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding) and use [google_project_iam_member](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_member) resources.

My current understanding could fall on in using `google_project_iam_binding` to grant roles to service accounts and `google_project_iam_member` to user accounts, but I am not sure since in the documentation they use both to associate user accounts.

I also found this interesting article https://binx.io/nl/2021/12/16/how-to-name-your-google-project-iam-resources-in-terraform/

> As you know, Google IAM resources in Terraform come in three flavors:
>
> - [google_project_iam_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_policy) to define a complete policy for the project.
> - [google_project_iam_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding) to define all the members of a single role.
> - [google_project_iam_member](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_member) to define a single role binding for a single principal.

I didn't know the previous sentence and I would like to deep dive in the way I can use policies, and IAM roles in a better way for my purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam) states:

> - [`google_project_iam_binding`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding): Authoritative for a given role. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a list of members. Other
>   roles within the IAM policy for the project are preserved.
> - [`google_project_iam_member`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_member): Non-authoritative. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a new member. Other members for the role for
>   the project are preserved.

This means that `google_project_iam_binding` will grant a role to a list of members, and revokes it from any other member.

So if your project had two users e.g: `jane@example.com` and `joe@example.com` who both have `roles/editor` on the project. Running the following Terraform snippet will revoke `roles/editor` from `joe@example.com` as it's not present in the member list of `google_project_iam_binding`

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project" {
  project = "your-project-id"
  role    = "roles/editor"

  members = [
    "user:jane@example.com",
  ]
}
```

However, if you have for example `jane@example.com` and `joe@example.com` who both have `roles/editor` on the project. If you want to add a new editor (`somone@example.com`) without affecting the other roles/users, you can use `google_project_iam_member`

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "project" {
  project = "your-project-id"
  role    = "roles/editor"
  member  = "user:someone@example.com"
}
```

---

**Notes** from the documentation:

> `google_project_iam_policy` cannot be used in conjunction with
> `google_project_iam_binding`, `google_project_iam_member`, or
> `google_project_iam_audit_config` or they will fight over what your
> policy should be.

> `google_project_iam_binding` resources can be used in conjunction with
> `google_project_iam_member` resources only if they do not grant
> privilege to the same role.

See:

- [Terraform google_project_iam_binding deletes GCP compute engine default service account from IAM principals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70703088/terraform-google-project-iam-binding-deletes-gcp-compute-engine-default-service)
- https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/difference-between-google-project-iam-binding-and-google-project-iam-member/49645/2
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8354

Comment: So is the conclusion here iam_member means adding just one person and iam_binding means adding a list of people?

Comment: no, `iam_binding` will grant a role to a list of member, and **revokes** it from any other member. And `iam_member` adds one, or a list of members: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam.html#member/members

Comment: Wow!  Your explanation is so much better than the documentation.  Thanks! :)